# Flow type for PanResponder like in example

Tags: react-native, flowtype

Cannot find flow type for PanResponder like shown in the official react-native example.

Example here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0ccedf3964b1ebff43e4631d1e60b3e733096e56/RNTester/js/examples/PanResponder/PanResponderExample.js#L17

This does not work:

```
import type {
  PanResponderInstance,
} from 'react-native';
```

For typing PanResponders:

```
// @flow

type Props = {…};
type State = {…};
class Screen extends Component<Props, State> {
  _panresponder: PanResponderInstance
  …
}
```

I want to use the flow type for PanResponder like in the example linked above. How can I access the type for PanResponder (PanResponderInstance) from react-native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import type {
   PanResponderInstance,
} from 'react-native';
```

This will work on react native 0.64

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out:

```
import type {
   PanResponderInstance,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/Interaction/PanResponder';
```

Sadly it seems like this is the way to do it, which is suboptimal but works.